# is there a correct way to add dynamically "forms" in a div-container with just JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Im trying to create a dynamic form just with html, css, and JavaScript (or a little bit of JQuery) so my ploblem is I have this:

```
<div class="form-item">
                   <label for="form-container">Random Title:</label>
                   <div id="form-container">
                       ***Here is where I add dynamic "forms"***
                   </div>
                   <div>
                       <button type="button" class="add-form" onclick="AddForm()">Add form</button>
                   </div>
</div>
```

and the JavaScript is (I dont know if is the best solution but at least it works haha):

```
function addForm(){

    let container= document.getElementById('form-container');

    if (cnt<5){
        cnt+=1;
        container.innerHTML += `***the form but write on HTML format***`;
    } else {
        alert("¡you cant add anymore!");
    }

}
```

and I need something similar but to remove the forms that I added with the dynamic add button.

(form is between "" because it isnt actually a form it is just a div with inputs inside, because it is part of a bigger form with other inputs on other divs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) to use inline event handlers (`<button onclick=...`).

Here's a a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where [delegated handling](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) handles creation, submittal and deletion of maximally 5 dynamic forms within `div#form-container`.

[Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-4mvgft?file=index.js) for this code.

```js
const maxForms = 5;
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function createFormHTML(n) {
  if (n > maxForms) {
    return alert(`No more forms allowed`);
  }
  return `
    <div data-dynamicform="${n}">
      <input type="text" placeholder="type something!">
      <button class="submit">Submbit</button>
      <button class="erase">Delete form</button>
    </div>`;
}

function handle(evt) {
  console.clear();
  
  if (evt.target.classList.contains(`add-form`)) {
    const container = document.querySelector(`#form-container`);
    container.dataset.nforms = +container.dataset.nforms + 1;
    const newForm = createFormHTML(+container.dataset.nforms);
    return newForm && container
      .insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, newForm) || true;
  }
  
  if( evt.target.classList.contains(`submit`)) {
    return console.log(`submitted form #${
      evt.target.closest(`[data-dynamicform]`).dataset.dynamicform}`);
  }
  
  if (evt.target.classList.contains(`erase`)) {
    evt.target.closest(`[data-dynamicform]`).remove();
    const dynamicForms = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-dynamicform]`);
    dynamicForms.length && dynamicForms
      .forEach( (form, i) => form.dataset.dynamicform = i + 1 );
    document.querySelector(`#form-container`).dataset.nforms = 
      dynamicForms.length;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1rem;
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana,arial;
}

#form-container {
  padding: 4px;
}

#form-container [data-dynamicform] {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-item">
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="add-form">Add form</button>
  </div>
  <div id="form-container" data-nforms="0">
    <h4>Your forms</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```